# Unity build to UWP: Windows app cert kit

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, uwp

I am having an issue with the Windows App Cert Kit not running on my machine.

I have tried

- re-installing dev kit
- Restarting my PC
- Running it as admin
- Opening the app from command line

re-installing the windows dev kit in several versions, restarting my PC,

[image]

I am trying to certify my Unity game for the Windows app store.

I have Windows 10 64-bit Home edition.

Comment: What's the build version of the windows on your machine? If just check the prompt message, it seemed that you would need to update your windows SDK, because the WACK is contained in windows SDK. You could check this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) to install the proper windows SDK version.

Comment: Windows 10 Version 1703, OS Build 15063.674. I have downloaded that SDK already and installed it

Comment: It's very strange. If you have installed the correct windows SDK(e.g, 15063), the WACK version should be like `Windows App Cert Kit 10.0.15063.137`, not "Windows App Cert Kit 3.4". Besides, what's your project's target version? What's version of your visual studio?

Comment: In Unity, when I built the project, I tried with both the "Latest Version" and the `10.0.15063`. I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, but I don't think that should matter. I can't even open the WACK regularly in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Windows 10 was not letting me use the WACK until I uninstalled the Windows 8.1 SDK, and re-installed the Windows 10 SDK again.

For some reason, even if you got to the install location and select the `appcert.exe`, windows wanted to open the 8.1 version, which would not work on Windows 10.